# OpenCV::solvePNP() - Assertion failed

Tags: opencv, runtime-error, pose-estimation

I am trying to get the pose of the camera with the help of solvePNP() from OpenCV.

After running my program I get the following errors:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F))) in solvePnP, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp, line 55
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I tried to search how to solve these errors, but I couldn't resolve it unfortunately!

Here is my code, all comment/help is much appreciated:

```
enum Pattern { NOT_EXISTING, CHESSBOARD, CIRCLES_GRID, ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID };

void calcBoardCornerPositions(Size boardSize, float squareSize, vector<Point3f>& corners,
                          Pattern patternType)
{
    corners.clear();

    switch(patternType)
    {
    case CHESSBOARD:
    case CIRCLES_GRID:
        for( int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; ++i )
            for( int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; ++j )
                corners.push_back(Point3f(float( j*squareSize ), float( i*squareSize ), 0));
        break;

    case ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID:
        for( int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++ )
                corners.push_back(Point3f(float((2*j + i % 2)*squareSize), float(i*squareSize), 0));
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float squareSize = 50.f;

    Pattern calibrationPattern = CHESSBOARD;

    //vector<Point2f> boardCorners;
    vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints(1);
    vector<vector<Point3f> > boardPoints(1);

    Size boardSize;
    boardSize.width = 9;
    boardSize.height = 6;

    vector<Mat> intrinsics, distortion;
    string filename = "out_camera_xml.xml";
    FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
    fs["camera_matrix"] >> intrinsics;
    fs["distortion_coefficients"] >> distortion;
    fs.release();

    vector<Mat> rvec, tvec;
    Mat img = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); // at kell adnom egy kepet

    bool found = findChessboardCorners(img, boardSize, imagePoints[0], CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH);

    calcBoardCornerPositions(boardSize, squareSize, boardPoints[0], calibrationPattern);
    boardPoints.resize(imagePoints.size(),boardPoints[0]);

    //***Debug start***
    cout << imagePoints.size() << endl << boardPoints.size() << endl << intrinsics.size() << endl << distortion.size() << endl;
    //***Debug end***

    solvePnP(Mat(boardPoints), Mat(imagePoints), intrinsics, distortion, rvec, tvec);

    for(int i=0; i<rvec.size(); i++) {
            cout << rvec[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT (some debug info):**

I debugged it row by row. I stepped into all of the functions. I am getting the Assertion failed in SolvePNP(...). You can see below what I see when I step into the solvePNP function. First it jumps over the first if statement /*if(vec.empty())*/, and goes into the second if statement /*if( !copyData )*/, there when it executes the last line /*datalimit = dataend = datastart + rows*step[0]*/ jumps back to the first if statement and returns => than I get the Assertion failed error.

```
template<typename _Tp> inline Mat::Mat(const vector<_Tp>& vec, bool copyData)
: flags(MAGIC_VAL | DataType<_Tp>::type | CV_MAT_CONT_FLAG),
dims(2), rows((int)vec.size()), cols(1), data(0), refcount(0),
datastart(0), dataend(0), allocator(0), size(&rows)
{
    if(vec.empty())
        return;
    if( !copyData )
    {
        step[0] = step[1] = sizeof(_Tp);
        data = datastart = (uchar*)&vec[0];
        datalimit = dataend = datastart + rows*step[0];
    }
    else
        Mat((int)vec.size(), 1, DataType<_Tp>::type, (uchar*)&vec[0]).copyTo(*this);
}
```

Comment: Please include some debug info, such as the line in from which the exception is thrown.

Comment: Hello! I had a little mistake in the code, what I edited now, but it still gives me a similar error. The program stops after the solvePNP(...) function. Everything gets executed before it, and nothing after it.

Comment: I added some debug info.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I encounter the same problem. I work in VC++ with OpenCV2.3.

Comment: I solved the problem as i said in my comment below...but thats not a real solution, tho was good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Step into the function in a debugger and see exactly which assertion is failing. ( Probably it requires values in double (CV_64F) rather than float. )

OpenCVs new "inputarray" wrapper issuppsoed to allow you to call functions with any shape of mat, vector of points, etc - and it will sort it out. But a lot of functions assume a particular inut format or have obsolete assertions enforcing a particular format.

The stereo/calibration systems are the worst for requiring a specific layout, and frequently succesive operations require a different layout.

Comment: Hello!
I added some debug info, but I didn't get any further. Do you see anything there?

Comment: The only time I've used solvePnP directly I fed it a vector<point3d> and vector<point2d> do you need to collapse the vector of vectors down to a single array?

Comment: The problem is...what I don't know why I didn't see while I was debugging...that for some reason the FileStorage doesn't reads in the data from the xml file...if I give it manually by hand, than it works! Now the only thing is, how to use rvec and tvec for finding the distance between the camera and the chessboard...but I guess thats a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

The types don't seem right, at least in the code that worked for me I used different types(as mentioned in the documentation).

> **objectPoints** – Array of object points in the object coordinate space, 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel, where N is the number of points. vector can be also passed here.
>
> **imagePoints** – Array of corresponding image points, 2xN/Nx2 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 2-channel, where N is the number of points.
> vector can be also passed here.
>
> **cameraMatrix** – Input camera matrix  A = \vecthreethree{fx}{0}{cx}{0}{fy}{cy}{0}{0}{1} .
>
> **distCoeffs** – Input
> vector of distortion coefficients  (k_1, k_2, p_1, p_2[, k_3[, k_4,
> k_5, k_6]]) of 4, 5, or 8 elements. If the vector is NULL/empty, the
> zero distortion coefficients are assumed.
>
> **rvec** – Output rotation vector (see Rodrigues() ) that, together with tvec , brings points from the model coordinate system to the
> camera coordinate system.
>
> **tvec** – Output translation vector.
>
> **useExtrinsicGuess** – If true (1), the function uses the provided rvec and tvec values as initial
> approximations of the rotation and translation vectors, respectively,
> and further optimizes them.

[Documentation from here.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags))

`vector<Mat> rvec, tvec` should be `Mat rvec, tvec` instead.

`vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints(1)` should be `vector<Point2f> imagePoints(1)` instead.

`vector<vector<Point3f> > boardPoints(1)` should be
`vector<Point3f> boardPoints(1)` instead.

Note: I encountered the exact same problem, and this worked for me(It is a little bit confusing since **calibrateCamera** use vectors). Haven't tried it for imagePoints or boardPoints though.(but as it is documented in the link above, **vector**,**vector** should work, I thought I'd better mention it), but for **rvec**,**trec** I tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I run in exactly the same problem with solvePnP and opencv3. I tried to isolate the problem in a single test case. I seams passing a std::vector to cv::InputArray does not what is expected. The following small test works with opencv 2.4.9 but not with 3.2.

And this is exactly the problem when passing a std::vector of points to solvePnP and causes the assert at line 63 in solvepnp.cpp to fail !

Generating a cv::mat out of the vector list before passing to solvePnP works.

```
//create list with 3 points
std::vector<cv::Point3f> vectorList;
vectorList.push_back(cv::Point3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
vectorList.push_back(cv::Point3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
vectorList.push_back(cv::Point3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

//to input array
cv::InputArray inputArray(vectorList);
cv::Mat mat = inputArray.getMat();
cv::Mat matDirect = cv::Mat(vectorList);

LOG_INFO("Size vector: %d mat: %d matDirect: %d", vectorList.size(), mat.checkVector(3, CV_32F), matDirect.checkVector(3, CV_32F));

QVERIFY(vectorList.size() == mat.checkVector(3, CV_32F));
```

Result opencv 2.4.9 macos:

```
TestObject: OpenCV
Size vector: 3 mat: 3 matDirect: 3
```

Result opencv 3.2 win64:

```
TestObject: OpenCV
Size vector: 3 mat: 9740 matDirect: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case, (in python) converted the input array type as float.

It worked fine afterwards.